# Login Simultâneo banco de dados - Eficiência

Tags: php, sql, login

Olá!

Para proibir login simultâneo de um mesmo usuário em um sistema local PHP, onde possuirá no máximo 50 usuários a longo prazo (inicialmente entre 15 e 20), criei uma tabela no banco de dados, aonde dados de uma sessão é inserida a cada vez que o usuário faz login nas colunas (id,id_usuario,created), sendo que o sistema faz a verificação se há alguma ativa com o ID do usuário. Caso encontre é redirecionado para uma página aonde pode optar por destruir todas as sessões ou manter a sessão ativa, em que nos dois casos retorna para a página de login, aonde na primeira opção passa por uma página de logout antes apagando registro no banco de dados (apagando registro no banco de dados, que mediante uma nova requisição do usuário "antigo" também será redirecionado para página de login. Atualizar a página não derruba ele), e na segunda não acontece nada (apenas o redirecionamento e mantendo registro da sessão do usuário antigo). Também fiz pela tag do HTML5 o redirecionamento em caso de inatividade por 1hr.

Uma das coisas que confesso que estou incomodado é o fato de a cada requisição de página ter de haver a consulta ao banco de dados para saber se a sessão está ativa, fazendo uma instanciação a cada requisição, tenho receio de que isso afete o desempenho...

1 - Gostaria de saber de vocês se acham essa solução eficiente para um sistema local?

2 - Percebi que o SQL, a cada nova inserção no BD mesmo que não tenha nenhum registro na tabela, ele incrementa o id da sessão de onde parou na inserção anterior... sei que o tipo INT tem um limite, quando for atingido ele voltará a incrementar a partir do 1 ou terei de mudar de tipo?

Answer (score 0):

Para validar se não existem múltiplos acessos com o mesmo usuário, apenas verifique no login se o usuário já tem uma sessão aberta, se houver trate como já faz, senão acesse normalmente. O usuário não tem como acessar outras paginas sem passar pelo login, então não precisa checar a cada requisição, somente no login.

Agora o campo INT armazena até 2.147.483.647, pela quantidade de usuários utilizando o sistema, você pode ficar tranquilo que suporta. Mas faça uma conta para validar.

Quantidade de logins diarios. Ex.: `50 usuarios x 100 logins = 5.000`, acho muito essa quantidade de logins, mas estou exagerando bastante. O INT vai até 2.147.483.647 então `2.147.483.647/5000 = 429.496 dias` e `429.496 / 365 = 1.176 anos`. Altere os valores de acessos para os reais e veja quanto tempo você levaria para preencher todos.

Obs.: Essa conta é para ilustrar o quanto é grande o valor do INT, mas outros fatores podem influenciar na escolha do tipo.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! 
Obs.: notei que quando desligo o note e não tenha ficado nenhuma sessão ativa, ele volta a inserir do ID 1 novamente! 
Com relação a checar a cada requisição a lógica é a seguinte: checa no login pra ver se possui sessão ativa para o usuário, se sim redireciona para derrubar ou manter sessão antiga, e a cada requisição de página para ver se possui sessão ativa (comparando login e id da sessão) para que ele não possa continuar navegando normalmente depois de "derrubado", sendo que haverá outra sessão com seu login, o que dará true, mas por consultar o ID da sessão será F